# PostgreSQL 9.5.6 update statement runs forever

Tags: performance, postgresql

Suddenly we entered a problem

We have a small table on which we are doing an update

Usually, it takes 2 seconds. But now it will never finish

I was looking in the `pg_stat_activity` table but there is no other query in the transaction and no locks.

If  I cancel the query pg_cancel_backend and rerun it 
it finishes without any problem

But 1 day later it happened again

and I don't know any other source than the pg_stat_activity where I can have a look.

In the postgresql.log there is nothing curious

does anybody have any suggestion what else could be the Problem?

Comment: and where is your tables schema/query?

Comment: ... and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the short query and `EXPLAIN` for the one that never finishes.